# When is postgres database created?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I'm running `pg_ctl init` or `initdb` to initialise cluster.
When is the exact moment the default database inside this cluster is created?

- In the initdb procedure?
- After I run the server?
- After the first connection to the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html)

> Creating a database cluster consists of creating the directories in which the database data will live, generating the shared catalog tables (tables that belong to the whole cluster rather than to any particular database), **and creating the `template1` and `postgres` databases**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So it's created when you run `initdb`

Answer (score 1):

To see:

```
/usr/local/pgsql14/bin/initdb -D data/
cd data/
ls -al base/
drwx------  2 postgres users 4096 Feb  9 08:17 1
drwx------  2 postgres users 4096 Feb  9 08:17 13596
drwx------  2 postgres users 4096 Feb  9 08:17 13597

ls -al base/1
total 8304
drwx------ 2 postgres users   4096 Feb  9 08:17 .
drwx------ 5 postgres users   4096 Feb  9 08:17 ..
-rw------- 1 postgres users   8192 Feb  9 08:17 112
-rw------- 1 postgres users   8192 Feb  9 08:17 113
-rw------- 1 postgres users 114688 Feb  9 08:17 1247
-rw------- 1 postgres users  24576 Feb  9 08:17 1247_fsm
-rw------- 1 postgres users   8192 Feb  9 08:17 1247_vm
...
```

From here [Database File Layout]:

> base   Subdirectory containing per-database subdirectories

So the 'system' databases are built upon using `init(db)`.